# Module or Incorrect Python Version Problem?

Tags: python, module

I'm installing a bunch of python modules on my system that are specific to this code I am going to be working with.  Specifically, I used pip install pyda to get the pyda module.  To make sure I had gotten all the modules, I went through and ran some of the code snippets, and came across the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyda.utilities'

I tried using pip install pyda.utilities, but that honestly doesn't make sense, it should have just come with the pyda module.  According to this website https://pypi.org/project/pyda/ it seems like it should come with the package.  I tried determining if I just installed it in the wrong python version, but I'm having a difficult time forcing it to use the specific python version that I installed the module in (specifically, I tried to create an alias for /usr/bin/python3.7 or something like this as I have seen on other websites, but it just fusses at me that this is simply a directory, incredibly unhelpful because I can't find the corresponding executable, so I'm a bit confused here).

This is a very long question likely with a very simple answer, any thoughts or help on what the issue might be would be appreciated.

Edit: I have determined that it's a package problem, not a python problem.  The command 'pip install pyda' is not actually installing everything, oddly enough, which is why it cannot find the pyda.utilities module.  Unfortunately, I think this means I will have to install the package manually.  I will keep this question posted because of the useful answer on virtual environments, so thanks everyone.

Comment: Try to see what Python version pip is installing modules to. What OS are you using? If you're on mac or linux run the command `pip -V` in a terminal and see what python version pip is installing to.

Comment: "I'm installing a bunch of python modules on my system that are specific to this code I am going to be working with"—that's a pretty common thing. I _strongly_ urge you to create a virtualenv for each project to keep these modules isolated.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about that @Rafi Levy.  I knew where it was being installed, since I had gone digging in my four different python options, but `pip -V` confirmed that.  My concern is that when I use `python file.py` I know it's using python 3 but I can't tell which python it's using.  I can figure out the version, but I have similar versions in different directories, and I can't figure out how to determine which directory is being used.  I would assume `pip install` should install things into the active python directory, but I'm not 100% positive on this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is indeed straightforward. As @Chris indicated in the comments, start using virtual environments.

It's not as complicated as it sounds and there's plenty of tutorials on getting started with `virtualenv` for Python, like https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/26/python-virtual-env/

The basic steps:

- check you're using the version of Python you want in your virtual environment
- if you don't, change directories to where it lives
- ensure you have `pip` and it works
- check if you have `virtualenv` and if you don't `pip install virtualenv`
- create a virtual environment `virtualenv /your/env/folder/here`
- activate the virtual environment with `/your/env/folder/here/Scripts/activate`

After that, just install the packages you need with `pip` and they will end up in your virtual environment, with no interference from other Python versions or packages.

Comment: I tried this, and then tried to use pip install but it said everything I needed was already installed (since I had already downloaded the modules directly), so I'm a bit confused.  It still says the pyda.utilities package is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Check your python version, if it does not work restart your computer and try run setup.py install on the python command line

Comment: I have checked my python version, but I have two different python3.7 versions: one under /usr/bin/..... and the other under /miniconda3/lib/...., but I don't know which one of these it is using.  That's my concern.  I know pip install is installing all my modules under the miniconda3 library.  My question is: is pip installing in the incorrect python directory (the one I'm not using when I run the command `python file.py`), or is pyda.utilities just not part of pyda?  The second answer doesn't make sense to me because the man page for pyda indicates it does have a utilities submodule.

Comment: Uninstall one of the python if you are on windows search for Apps and check for the python version you want to uninstall